# Web Scraping with R - {xml_nodeset (0)}

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm new to R and I'm trying to get data from this website: https://spritacular.org/gallery.
I want to get the location, time and the hour. I am following this [guide](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), using the SelectorGadget I clicked on the elements I wanted (.card-title , .card-subtitle , .mb-0).
However, it always outputs {xml_nodeset (0)} and I'm not sure why it's not getting those elements.

This is the code I have:

```
url <- "https://spritacular.org/gallery"
sprite_gallery <- read_html(url)

sprite_location <- html_nodes(sprite_gallery, ".card-title , .card-subtitle , .mb-0")

sprite_location
```

When I change the website and grab something from a different website it works, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it, this is my first time doing something like this and I appreciate any insight you may have!

Comment: The web page requires JavaScript, thus rvest isn’t working.  From the network tabs from your browser’s developer tool menu you can download the underlying json data.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment, this website has JS embedded and the information only opens when a browser is opened. If you go to developers tools and network tab, you can see the underlying json data
[image]
If you post a `GET` request for this api address, you will get a list back with all the results. From their, you can slice and dice your way to get the required information you need.

One way to do this: I have considered the name of the user who submitted the image and I found out that same user has submitted multiple images. Hence there are duplicate names and locations in the output but the image URL is different. Refer [this blog](https://themockup.blog/posts/2020-05-22-parsing-json-in-r-with-jsonlite/) to know how to drill down the json data to make useful dataframes in R

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)

getURL <- 'https://api.spritacular.org/api/observation/gallery/?category=&country=&cursor=cD0xMTI%3D&format=json&page=1&status='

# get the raw json into R
UOM_json <- httr::GET(getURL) %>% 
  httr::content()

exp_output <- pluck(UOM_json, 'results') %>%
  enframe() %>%
  unnest_longer(value) %>%
  unnest_wider(value) %>%
  select(user_data, images) %>%
  unnest_wider(user_data) %>%
  mutate(full_name = paste(first_name, last_name)) %>%
  select(full_name, location, images) %>%
  rename(., location_user = location) %>%
  unnest_longer(images) %>%
  unnest_wider(images) %>%
  select(full_name, location, image)
```

Output of our `exp_output`

```
> head(exp_output)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  full_name     location                          image                                                                                
  <chr>         <chr>                             <chr>                                                                                
1 Kevin Palivec Jones County,Texas,United States  https://d1dzduvcvkxs60.cloudfront.net/observation_image/1d4cc82f-f3d2…
2 Kamil Świca   Lublin,Lublin Voivodeship,Poland  https://d1dzduvcvkxs60.cloudfront.net/observation_image/3b6391d1-f839…
3 Kamil Świca   Lublin,Lublin Voivodeship,Poland  https://d1dzduvcvkxs60.cloudfront.net/observation_image/9bcf10d7-bd7c…
4 Kamil Świca   Lublin,Lublin Voivodeship,Poland  https://d1dzduvcvkxs60.cloudfront.net/observation_image/a7dea9cf-8d6e…
5 Evelyn Lapeña Bulacan,Central Luzon,Philippines https://d1dzduvcvkxs60.cloudfront.net/observation_image/539e0870-c931…
6 Evelyn Lapeña Bulacan,Central Luzon,Philippines https://d1dzduvcvkxs60.cloudfront.net/observation_image/c729ea03-e1f8…
>
```